# A1Notation conversion to row & column index

Tags: javascript, performance, regex, google-apps-script

This set of Google Apps Script helper functions are published in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0), along with a bunch of other utilities. Background info is in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112522/how-to-get-row-column-values-from-a1notation). Since no Google services are used, this is pure JavaScript.

What I hope to get from a code review:

- General feedback on clarity & maintainability.
- Is the regex in `cellA1ToIndex()` too big a drag on performance? What alternatives would be as-or-more functional, with better performance?

**`cellA1ToIndex( string cellA1, number index )`**

Convert a cell reference from `A1Notation` to 0-based indices (for arrays) or 1-based indices (for Spreadsheet Service methods).

**`colA1ToIndex( colA1, index )`**

Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet column label, as in A1 notation.

**`rowA1ToIndex( string rowA1, number index )`**

Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet row number, as in A1 notation. Almost pointless, really, but maintains symmetry with `colA1ToIndex()`.

```
/**
 * Convert a cell reference from A1Notation to 0-based indices (for arrays)
 * or 1-based indices (for Spreadsheet Service methods).
 *
 * @param {String}    cellA1   Cell reference to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {object}            {row,col}, both 0-based array indices.
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 */
function cellA1ToIndex( cellA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  // Use regex match to find column & row references.
  // Must start with letters, end with numbers.
  // This regex still allows induhviduals to provide illegal strings like "AB.#%123"
  var match = cellA1.match(/(^[A-Z]+)|([0-9]+$)/gm);

  if (match.length != 2) throw new Error( "Invalid cell reference" );

  var colA1 = match[0];
  var rowA1 = match[1];

  return { row: rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ),
           col: colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) };
}

/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet column
 * label, as in A1 notation.
 *
 * @param {String}    colA1    Column label to be converted.
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 */
function colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) {
  if (typeof colA1 !== 'string' || colA1.length > 2) 
    throw new Error( "Expected column label." );

  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  var A = "A".charCodeAt(0);

  var number = colA1.charCodeAt(colA1.length-1) - A;
  if (colA1.length == 2) {
    number += 26 * (colA1.charCodeAt(0) - A + 1);
  }
  return number + index;
}



/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet row
 * number, as in A1 notation. Almost pointless, really, but maintains
 * symmetry with colA1ToIndex().
 *
 * @param {Number}    rowA1    Row number to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 */
function rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  return rowA1 - 1 + index;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this code always assigns 1 to index: `index == index || 0; index = 0 ? 0 : 1;` Perhaps you meant something like `index = (index) ? 1 : 0` ?

Comment: @gengkev Good one! Bug there with `==`, should be `=`, assignment. Intent is to first default to zero if not defined, then enforce zero or one.

Comment: You could also make that one line `index = (index || 0) && 1;`

Comment: @SpiderPig - Ah, yes, relying on coercion of the boolean to a number 0 or 1. Slick. What about readability / supportability?

Comment: @gengkev - I've fixed the bug you pointed out, in all three locations. Also in gist. Thanks!

Comment: fine, then what about `index = index ? 1 : 0;` ?

Comment: @SpiderPig - that's sexy, and (for me at least) is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you fixed the `index`-checking/defaulting bug that gengkev pointed out in the comments. As SpiderPig mentioned the cleanest solution is probably `index = index ? 1 : 0`.

However, I don't know if I'd bother with the `index` parameter at all. So far, it's led to bugs, duplication across all three functions, and all it really does is add/subtract 1. That can be done anywhere.

So I'd recommend just translating to 1-based indices, and if you need zero-based indices, well, subtract 1.

I wouldn't worry about using a regex - but I'd probably make it stricter. I imagine that a cell reference isn't *that* flexible. I imagine the string may contain `"$"`s but that's about it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

However, `cellA1ToIndex()` also does too much. It checks things that the other two functions don't. So if you call the other two functions directly, your input isn't checked as strictly. For instance, `colA1ToIndex()` will accept a string like `"%#"`, and return something wrong. Similarly, `rowA1ToIndex()` will gladly accept just about anything, and return `NaN`.

So I'd keep `cellA1ToIndex` as "dumb" as possible, and make sure the specialized functions are more robust.

Lastly, why a of maximum 2 letters for columns? Why not 3? Or 4?

I'd do something like this:

```
function cellA1ToIndex(cellA1) {
  var match = cellA1.match(/^\$?([A-Z]+)\$?(\d+)$/);

  if(!match) {
    throw new Error( "Invalid cell reference" );
  }

  return {
    row: rowA1ToIndex(match[2]),
    col: colA1ToIndex(match[1])
  };
}

function colA1ToIndex(colA1) {
  var i, l, chr,
      sum = 0,
      A = "A".charCodeAt(0),
      radix = "Z".charCodeAt(0) - A + 1;

  if(typeof colA1 !== 'string' || !/^[A-Z]+$/.test(colA1)) {
    throw new Error("Expected column label");
  }

  for(i = 0, l = colA1.length ; i < l ; i++) {
    chr = colA1.charCodeAt(i);
    sum = sum * radix + chr - A + 1
  }

  return sum;
}

function rowA1ToIndex(rowA1) {
  var index = parseInt(rowA1, 10)
  if(isNaN(index)) {
    throw new Error("Expected row number");
  }
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, many good points! Counter-points & answers to your questions: While subtracting 1 can be done _anywhere_, that in itself leads to bugs. Six of one, etc. "Cell references not that flexible" - true. As for `$`, I had intentionally ignored it, but stripping it first would be effective. Pushing the richer checking down into the specialized functions is smart, thanks. Why 2 column letters? Old sheets allowed a max of 256 columns, so 2 was all you could use. (And the whole range wouldn't be legal - but later _use_ of the col number would generate exceptions.) Now 2M cells: limit not needed.